# Views PHP : couldn't print dates

Tags: views

I'm using [views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) to printing, and calculate some dates in my view.but when I try to print a date (06/01/2015) in the global php field it printed like: 16831 which is the node id
Value code:

> $load=$row->field_date_loading;
>   return $load;

Out put code:

> echo $value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$load = $data->field_field_date_loading[0]['raw']['value'];
echo $load;
```

if you are using an end date as well you can get it with:

```
$data->field_field_date_loading[1]['raw']['value'];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing is printed

Comment: oh it works only if i use the code in out put code without passing the $value variable.

Comment: Works perfectly on a fresh install with drupal + views + views PHP. And you are suppose to put it in the output code.